# Optimizing jquery selector for Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, optimization, jquery-selectors

I have the following jquery code to loop over 525 (I know, alot!) checkboxes:

```
var elements = $("#profile-list table tr input[type=checkbox].email-checkout:not(:checked)");

$.each(elements, function(i) {
    $(elements[i]).attr('checked', 'checked');
});
```

**UPDATE** The html looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>E-mail</th>
        <th>Telephone</th>
        <th id="email_check"><img src="check_black.png"/></th>
   </tr>
   <?php foreach ($this->profiles as $profile): ?>
        <tr>
            <?php echo $this->presentProfile($profile, 'list') ?>
        </tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
```

This basically loops over all profiles in the database and creates a table row for each profile, where the last table data includes a checkbox, which one can select to send email to. If the user clicks the table header with the id of "email_check" then the javascript code should kick in, and that's where Chrome fails.

I attach the event with the following code:

```
$("#email_check img").live('click', function() {
     //my code
}
```

When I run this code in Firefox (mac), it goes smoothly but when I run it in Chrome (mac) it takes forever and ends up giving me the window where chrome offers me the option of killing the window, so basically it never completes this loop.

I've been trying to optimize this selector as much as I can, and since jquery 1.3, I understand that they switched from left to right to right to left selector, which basically means that I should try to make my right most selector as specific as I can. Can it be any more specific than I currently have?

Or is it the loop that just takes so long? I have tried switching from $.each to just a regular for() without a positive result.

Any tips or ideas how I can fix this?

Ingiber

Comment: is that a stable Chrome version, or a development one? that could make a difference, too

Comment: I'm using version 7.0.517.44 on mac, which I guess is a stable one

Comment: Also try in Safari. Safari and Chrome share the same engine....

Comment: It works fine in Safari, takes about 1 second or so. So it is not a webkit problem.

Comment: @Šime Vidas - They both use Webkit, but they have different javascript engines. Safari has SquirrelFish, while Chrome has V8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't think this is a selector issue at all.

Your selector is a valid selector for `querySelectorAll`, which means it will be extremely fast.

I tested the exact selector  in Chrome on Mac against a table with 250 rows, and the result was instantaneous.

I'd guess that there's something else going on.

Comment: @Indyber - The strange part is that the issue is unique to Chrome. It's javascript engine is *extremely* fast. If you could post more code, it would be helpful.

Comment: @Indyber - Taking a look. You're using the latest jQuery, right? Also, it would be helpful if the HTML in your question was an actual sample of the HTML rendered by your PHP.

Comment: @Indyber - [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/traAj/) using your code against a table with 550 rows. Runs perfectly for me in Chrome. Although as @Nick stated, it is much better to do `this.checked = true` to set the checked property.

Comment: @patrick - Nice, thanks for that. This shows for sure that there's something else going on. I'll go back to my code and try to debug it properly. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `table tr` part of the selector.  It isn't adding anything.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
// console.time("test");

var elements = $("#profile-list input[type=checkbox].email-checkout").get();
var len = elements.length;

for (var i = 0; i < len; i += 1) {
    elements[i].checked = true;
}

// console.timeEnd("test");
```

(So, first we select all check-boxes that are of the class "email-checkout" and are inside the #profile-list element. Then we just set their checked property to true. I assume, this is as fast as it can be.)

Comment: I like your idea, but it gives the same result.

Comment: @Indyber I would love to know the performance improvement of my code compared to your original code. You can use console.time() and console.timeEnd() to measure it like so: `console.time("test"); /* the code */ console.timeEnd("test");` Then, check the console to view the results...

Comment: Very interesting. I did the test in Firefox and my solution took 28ms, while your solution only took 14ms, good job! But still Chrome has some problems with it.

Comment: @Indyber Wait, 30ms in Firefox and about 1 second in Safari. That is really odd. From what I know, Safari has a faster JavaScript engine ...

Comment: 1 second in safari was completely based on my gut feeling of time awareness :) let me test it properly...

Comment: Well, I wasn't that far off, it actually takes 1399 ms in Safari

Comment: @Indyber Also, it could be helpful to know how Safari handles your code vs. my code. What is the time difference in Safari?

Answer (score 0):

You could always give each check box a select/deselect event that will add/remove a class from the checkbox, then use the class as the selector.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) on the set to use the elements directly, like this:

```
$("#profile-list table tr input[type=checkbox].email-checkout").each(function() {
  this.checked = true;
});
```

Also note the removal of `:not(:checked)` above...if you're going to check them all, that selector is more expensive that actually checking them anyway.  More importantly is that `this.checked = true;` is *tremendously* cheaper than `$(elements[i]).attr('checked', 'checked');` which happens *every* time.

Comment: This still failed in Chrome, but it took only 18ms in Firefox, so is definitely an improvement to my own solution

Comment: @Indyber - do you have a link to your page?

Comment: It's on an internal server blocked from the outside, so that's not possible. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Did you profile this?  What is taking too long, getting the elements or looping over them?  The only way to really speed up code is to profile and fix the slow parts.

FWIW, I would try

```
var elements = $("#profile-list").find("input[type=checkbox].email-checkout").get();

...
```

and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Add an onlclick on the checkbox

```
$("#profile-list input[type=checkbox].email-checkout").click(function() {
    var obj = $(this);
    obj.hasClass("checked") ? obj.removeClass("checked") : obj.addClass("checked");
});

s = $("input[type=checkbox].email-checkout.checked");
```